# Mouse randomly scrolls

Tags: 18.04

I have Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS and since yesterday my wireless mouse randomly scrolls. Last week the mouse was working fine.
When I scroll down it will go down but then jump up a bit and vice versa. Shortly after scrolling it sometimes randomly scrolls.

- I swapped out my mouse and receiver for another mouse of same model but the problem persists.
- I changed USB ports as well.
- Trackpad is disabled.
- Batteries are new
- When I unplug the mouse, re-enable trackpad and scroll using trackpad there is no problem with scrolling. So there is no other input that causes this behavior

Mouse is Modecom MC-WM101 and is reported as 'Telink Wireless Receiver Mouse'

Answer (score 1):

Something is triggering the scrolling and it can be literately anything. My laptop had a little pointing stick/joystick between G H and B that had a wander, the reason is that any analog input should have a dead-zone where it knows it's in a zero/non-moving state. If your colleague uses the same brand/type it may suffer from the same build. subconsciously you could use your finger to be slightly outside of this dead zone.

The mouse sensor can be dirty or the surface is difficult to scan. The Page Down button may be dirty or stutter. The batteries might be empty or a radio source can randomly jam your signal path. There might be a virus or a faulty driver/module. Or you have another input device connected that triggers this.

From a few sentences it's impossible to determine the cause in your circumstance, so start experimenting and troubleshooting until you find the trigger.

Comment: Last week it was working fine so I suspect a driver. How do I check which driver is installed and when it was updated?

Comment: https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/man/man4/mousedrv.4.xhtml

Comment: Xorg controls the higherlevel mouse, there should be a control panel where you can set the sensitivity. You can also use they xset command and some Xorg configuration files like described [her](https://www.pontikis.net/blog/fix-mouse-sensitivity-ubuntu). The lower level linux drivers you can see with "dmesg" and since you have a USB dongle it should be also listed with "lsusb". low level legacy emulation is done in the UEFI/BIOS.